# Navbar to stick to header when scrolling

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i am trying to get an effect working were the navbar is in the middle of the page and the user will scroll down , as he hits the navbar it should stick to the top of the page. example of this : [here](http://html.metrothemes.me/me/index-2.html#about)
You can see when the user scrolls down and hits the navbar it stick and its a nice slow effect.

I got mine to work but it feels cluncky , by that i mean it flicks to the top straight away unlike the example one were its very smooth and it smoothly sticks to the top while mine is very harsh.

```css
.parallax {
  background-color: Black;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax1 {
  background-color: Red;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  line-height: 38px
}

.navbar-nav>li>a.active {
  background-color: #E7E7E7
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #E7E7E7
}

.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  position: relative
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #2DCC70
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #000000
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="parallax"></div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="700">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#hometab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section1">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">My Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>1>

<div class="parallax1"></div>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: I updated my answer check that if any issue comment on the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to add on your style:

```
.affix + .parallax1 {
  margin-top: 70px;
}
```

the class `.affix` indicates that the nav is sticking at the top. So if the `.affix` is present on `nav`, you have to set margin or padding to `parallax1` so that the HELLO THERE text is not hiding behind the nav.

Editing your fiddle:

```css
.parallax {
  background-color: Black;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax1 {
  background-color: Red;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Add this */
.affix + .parallax1 {
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  line-height: 38px
}

.navbar-nav>li>a.active {
  background-color: #E7E7E7
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #E7E7E7
}

.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  position: relative
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #2DCC70
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #000000
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">

</div>



<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="700">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#hometab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section1">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">My Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="parallax1">
  <h1>
HELLO THERE
 </h1>

</div>
```

Comment: This example looks simple but I saw a jump in this a well thats why I used jquery my example does not show a jump very smooth.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the desired example works so smooth is because it utilizes a [smoothScroll](https://github.com/galambalazs/smoothscroll-for-websites) library. I simply included it in the example fiddle you provided and it works a lot more like the demo site you showed, check it out **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/82c16yz8/5/)**. You don't need to add any code on your part, since the library is already initialized once the page finishes loading:

```
addEvent(wheelEvent, wheel);
addEvent('mousedown', mousedown);
addEvent('load', init);
```

Let me know if you have any other questions : )

Answer (score 1):

Smooth sticky navbar it is using jquery 2. Hope this works for your testing. Keeps track of navbar on all screen size.

```js
var navOffset, scrollPos = 0;

function sticky() {
  if (!$(".navbar").hasClass("fixed")) {
    navOffset = $(".navbar").offset().top;
  }
}

sticky();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
    var ht = $(".navbar").outerHeight() + 10;
    $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    $(".nav-placeholder").css({
      'height': ht + "px",
      'display': 'block'
    });
  } else {
    $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");
    $(".nav-placeholder").css({
      'height': 0,
      'display': 'none'
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.parallax {
  background-color: Black;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parallax1 {
  background-color: Red;
  min-height: 700px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1
}

.navbar-nav {
  float: none;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
  line-height: 38px
}

.navbar-nav>li>a.active {
  background-color: #E7E7E7
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #E7E7E7
}

.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #000000;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  position: relative
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #2DCC70
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #000000
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent
}

.nav-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="parallax"></div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#hometab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section1">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">My Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Contact Me</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>
<p>Some text for test</p>
<div class="parallax1"></div>
```

Comment: OP: Please consider my answer instead. This answer adds the complexity of jQuery to the project + another third party library to achieve what Bootstrap already does for you (with your existing stickyness). All that's necessary for your original example to work, @RonTheOld, is to add a small smooth scroll lib (any of them will work) to your site.

Comment: Jquery is a dependencies of bootstrap so I never added extra files FYI

Comment: My bad @RajendranNadar, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

**Use bootstrap Class "navbar-fixed-top"**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="700">
```

Comment: Sorry i dont think u understand the question, i am going for the same look as the example i gave, so when the user scrolls and hits the navbar it flicks to the top

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this code, set affix value to navigation gap from top**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style>
      .affix {
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
      }

      .affix + .container-fluid {
          padding-top: 70px;
      }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#000;color:#fff;height:200px;">
      Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC

    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Basic Topnav</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid" style="height:1000px">
      <p>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </p>
      <p>
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
      </p>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```